# Does "Critical Strike Chance" increases the chance of assassinating?   

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Does "Critical Strike Chance" increases the chance of assassinating?

Since the "Assassination" scene is only shown if you have enough damage for one shotting the human in question, critical strike would raise the total damage of the strike. In theory this would allow you to to assassinate humans with more health points than you would be able to without a critical strike.

Also, would 15x damage with a decent dagger would be enough most of the times (at master difficulty) to assassinate the victim, making the critical strike chance an "overkill" in this situation ?

By "Decent Dagger" I mean : Mehrunes' razor, upgraded glass dagger or above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory if you critical while doing a backstab you are more likely to one-shot your target and thus have the chance to trigger the assassination animation (though I have become quite fond of the face to face animation as opposed to the from behind one).

It has been found out that most of the perks in the one handed tree actually do not affect daggers because of the bonuses they get from the assassination perk along with the Shrouded gloves making them do 30x damage total when used from stealth. Despite this, it should be noted that a critical strike from an assassination attack has been noted to do around 32,000 damage (which is why its understandable that the perks do not affect them :))... Even on Master with all the ups and downs there is nothing in the game that could actually survive that.

I have a set of Daedric daggers that are legendary, but they were just crafted with 100 skill, maybe a 10-15% smithing item I might have found along the way but no real effort into maxing out the stats on them.. I have had no problem one-shoting anything I have been able to sneak up upon with these.

I would say that in general the Critical Strike perks are a waste of perk points for an assassin. Further more an assassin should want to keep things on as much of an even keel as possible. If you are relying on a critical strike and it only happens 50% of the time, then you are going to fail half of the time. Much better to just work on getting a nice set of daggers to lead with so you can consistently kill anything that does not see you.

Comment: Perfect Answer. Thanks alot for taking time to write it. By the way, i was not considering spending points in the perks, i was talking about this dagger (http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Valdr's_Lucky_Dagger) that gives +25% chance to critical strike. But its damage is not that high. Still a waste probably

Comment: Ah, that dagger was not mentioned in the original question.. but yeah it would take a significant amount of work with alchemy and enchanting to smith that into a useful dagger.